# boost/asio.hpp и cmake, ошибка линкера

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

Мой код

```
#include "iostream"
#include "Utilities.cpp"
#include "boost/asio.hpp"

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Пытаюсь его собрать через cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(ProcessesManipulate)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(ProcessesManipulate main.cpp)
```

Получаю ошибку

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ProcessesManipulate.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::~posix_thread()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail12posix_threadD2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail12posix_threadD2Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Судя из ошибки, видно что линкер в бустовых библиотеках не может найти ссылку на `pthread_detach`. Почему так происходит? Я в коде подключаю заголовочный файл

```
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
```

И получаю ошибку что где то там что то валится по не понятным причинам. Погуглив, я нашел пару вариантов. Добавив вот такой хак

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(ProcessesManipulate PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

Все фиксится.
Почему я должен знать что `#include "boost/asio.hpp"` внутри юзает pthread_detach. Когда я делаю `#include "boost/asio.hpp"` оно разве автоматом не должно мне подгрузить все зависимости?

Comment: Потому что в линукс обычно всё строится именно на pthreads

Comment: *"Когда я делаю #include "boost/asio.hpp" оно разве автоматом не должно мне подгрузить все зависимости"* - конечно нет... ¿Первый день в С++? Тут надо линковать библиотеку pthread. *"Почему я должен знать что #include "boost/asio.hpp" внутри юзает pthread_detach."* - потому что так устроен С++, вам надо будет знать рекурсивно все зависимости интерфейса, указывать и контролировать их подключение вручную.

Comment: #include "iostream"
Почему тогда эту библиотеку линковать не надо?

Comment: iostream - это заголовочный файл стандартной библиотеки, вполне возможна ситуация, когда ее тоже надо будет явно линковать: когда компилятор собран без встроенной поддержки стандартной библиотеки или нужна статическая линковка или отличная от встроенной реализация

Comment: и например boost filesystem линковать не надо почему то...

Comment: в boost часть библиотек являются заголовочными. читайте документацию... и какой-нибудь ликбез по стадиям сборки, работе препроцессора и линкера.

Comment: есть какой то способ что бы автоматизировать линковку? Допустим у меня огромный проект, с десятками библиотек, и что мне придется запускать проект и каждый раз смотреть какая либа не прилинковалась что бы её вручную линковать или что?

Comment: Ну в общем да. Только обычно знать, какие либы надо линковать, надо еще до сборки. Для каждого символа надо знать, в каком файле он объявлен и в какой единице трансляции он определен. Автоматизации поддается только подставление соответствующих аргументов для линкера. На том же cmake можно написать минимальную систему сборки и простенькое управление зависимостями.

Comment: А можно мне ссылочку на материал что бы почитать про зависимости и про автоматизацию сборки?